# jar library not found after reloading in IntelliJ/Scala

Tags: java, scala, jar, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ, I have a project A, and I export the project as A.jar. 
With another project B, I use the jar file in Project Settings/Libraries.

[image]

It works fine, however, when I close the project B, and reload the project B, the classes in the A.jar file is not found.

[image]

What's wrong with this? Is this a bug, or I use the wrong method to use other project's exported jar files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

Instead of importing jar, importing a directory that contains the class files.

### Solution 2

Create a lib directory side by side with src directory. Then, copy or symbolic link the jar file to import. Import this jar file from lib directory.

This approach works better because it will work well with sbt.